# How can the state be shared between the returned result and the next iteration when using the scan iterator?

Tags: rust

I would like to use the `Scan` iterator to construct a vector in a declarative fashion. It is clear how to achieve this by copying the intermediate state. The following expression compiles and produced the desired series:

```
let vec = (0..10).scan(0, |state, current| {
    *state = *state + current;
    Some(*state)
}).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

However, if I try to achieve the same behavior by moving the state instead of copying it, I get in trouble with lifetimes. For example, when working with vectors instead of integers, one cannot move the state out of the closure and reuse it in the next iteration. The expression

```
let vec = (0..10).map(|x| vec![x]).scan(vec![0], |state, current| {
    *state = vec![state[0] + current[0]];
    Some(*state)
}).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

fails to compile due to

```
error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
     Some(*state)
          ^~~~~~
```

see for example this [MVCE](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c7ca88d5b8906e0dbc65).

Borrowing the state instead of moving would also be an option:

```
let start = &vec![0];
let vec = (0..10).map(|x| vec![x]).scan(start, |state, current| {
    *state = &vec![state[0] + current[0]];
    Some(*state)
}).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

but this fails because the new value falls out of scope when the state is returned.

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
*state = &vec![state[0] + current[0]]
```

What I ended up doing is using the `for` loop

```
let xs = &mut Vec::<Vec<i32>>::with_capacity(10);
xs.push[vec!(0)];
for x in 1..10 {
    let z = vec![xs.last().unwrap()[0] + x];
    xs.push(z);
};
```

but I wold prefer a chaining solution.

Comment: Can you write out the vector you want to build?

Comment: Please produce a MVCE, preferably on the [playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/). As it is, it is unclear whether the result should be a `Vec<T>` or `Vec<Vec<T>>`, for example.

Comment: `scan` produces an iterator that internally stores the state. On each call of next, a mutable reference to that state is passed to the closure. That is why you cannot move the state. It would invalidate the iterator. Maybe you are looking for `fold`? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, and so cannot give a solution.

Comment: @A.B. Thank's for your explanation of the scan iterator, means that what I was trying to achieve with scan is impossible. I added a for loop which produces the vector I would like to produce. Any suggestion how to improve this? Using a single-entry vector just serves as example of a non-copy object.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Thank you for pointing out playpen, I created a minimal example accessible on  [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c7ca88d5b8906e0dbc65) .

Comment: @pbarmettler: It is better to have the MVCE accessible directly in the question so I edited in, and as a bonus now that I understood what you were trying to do I also answered ;) (took me some time to wrap my head around what that `scan` thing was about oO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check the definition of [`scan`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan):

> ```
> fn scan<St, B, F>(self, initial_state: St, f: F) -> Scan<Self, St, F>
>     where F: FnMut(&mut St, Self::Item) -> Option<B>
> ```

Note that `B` is distinct from `St`. The idea of `scan` is that:

- you keep an accumulator of type `St`
- at each iteration, you produce a value of type `B`

and indeed it is not quite suited to returning values of type `St` because you are only borrowing `St` and do not control its lifetime.

`scan` is made for you to return a brand new value each time:

```
let xs = (0..10).scan(0, |state, current| {
    *state += current;
    Some(NonCopy::new(*state))
}).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

and that's it!

---

A note on efficiency.

The *state* of `scan` is a sunk cost so it is best to use a cheap state (a single integer here).

If you need a larger type `X` and wish to "get your memory back", then you can pass an `&mut Option<X>` and then use `.take()` after the `scan`:

```
let mut x = Some(NonCopy::new(0));

let xs = (0..10).scan(&mut x, |state, current| {
    let i: &mut i32 = &mut state.as_mut().unwrap().value;
    *i += current;
    Some(NonCopy::new(*i))
}).collect::<Vec<_>>();

let _ = x.take();
```

It's not as elegant, of course.

Comment: Understood. I was trying to use `scan` for passing a large type and you clearly explained that this is not what it is meant for. The solution proposed in the second part of the answer looks interesting. But it is probably clearer to fill the vector using a for loop (or fold as shown in the answer of A.B.). Thanks.

Comment: @pbarmettler: Actually, you can absolutely pass a large type (especially by reference), what matters is that you cannot return a *reference* to said type (or anything computed locally).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to do it without cloning value using `scan` method.

When you return a non-`Copy` value from the closure, you lose ownership of that value. And it's not possible to keep any reference to it, because it's new owner could move the value in memory anywhere it wants (for example, during vector resizing), and Rust is intended to protect against this kind of errors.

Comment: Thank you swizard, this clarifies what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

By chaining solution, do you mean this?

```
let vec = (0..10)
    .fold((Vec::with_capacity(10), 0), |(mut vec, previous), x| {
        vec.push(vec![previous + x]);
        (vec, previous + x)
    })
    .0;
```

Comment: The fact that the fold statement can be used to replace the for loop (as shown in [link](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/add-foreach-method-to-iterators-for-side-effects/1312/2)) is clear, but I was looking for a way to pass the result of `previous+x` to the next step of the iteration. In your version you are still making a copy of `previous+x`.

Comment: @pbarmettler: But... anyway in the next step of the iteration you would be making a copy of it to be able to push it into the vector no? Would `(0..10).fold(Vec::with_capacity(10), |mut vec, x| { let new = if vec.is_empty() { vec![x] } else { vec![vec.back() + x] }; vec.push(new); vec });` work for you?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Yes, this works. I consider this equivalent to the `xs.push[vec!(0)]; for x in 1..10 { let z = vec![xs.last().unwrap()[0] + x]; xs.push(z);};` solution stated in my question. If one does not require lazy evaluation of the iteration this is a perfectly fine solution.